# JSON syntax error: 'unexpected number' or 'JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, syntax-error

I receive this response from a POST request using $.ajax():

```
{"command": 6,"log_size":50,"log":[
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0D","ti": 1047161877,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": " __START__","sensors": "00","ti": 0000011410,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0A","ti": 0000011411,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0B","ti": 0000011411,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0D","ti": 0000011412,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": " __START__","sensors": "00","ti": 1047215799,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0A","ti": 1047215799,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": " __START__","sensors": "00","ti": 1047218051,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0D","ti": 0000002598,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0B","ti": 1047068795,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0D","ti": 1047068796,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0A","ti": 1047071223,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0B","ti": 1047071224,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0D","ti": 1047071225,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0A","ti": 0000000010,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0D","ti": 0000000012,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0C","ti": 1047130533,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0A","ti": 0000000026,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0A","ti": 0000000180,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0B","ti": 0000000206,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "09","ti": 0000000212,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "08","ti": 0000000383,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": " __START__","sensors": "00","ti": 0000001562,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0A","ti": 0000001563,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0B","ti": 0000001564,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0D","ti": 1047161632,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": " __START__","sensors": "00","ti": 1047161875,"to": 0},
    {"type": 30,"tag": "*NETEVENT*","sensors": "0B","ti": 1047161876,"to": 0}
],
"response":"ok"}
```

For *IE* works fine, in *Chrome* appears `"Syntax error: unexpected number"` and in *Firefox* the message is `"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object"`

In various online JSON parsers and validators the format of the response seems to be OK, but in firefox and chrome not works.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I get a validation error about the value `0000000206` with the first JSON validator found on Google.

Comment: [this](http://jsonlint.com/) can be usefull to you in validating json string

Answer (score 70, accepted):

A number can't start with a not significative `0`.

This is invalid : `"ti": 0000011410`

From [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) :

[image]

You should fix it at the source but if you can't, **assuming your JSON is always similar to this one** (no numbers in strings), then you might probably fix it with a regex :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str.replace(/ 0+(?![\. }])/g, ' '));
```

You can't even here use the evil `eval` because `"0000011410"` would be parsed as a octal :

```
console.log(eval('({"ti": 0000011410})'));
```

outputs

```
{ti: 4872}
```

This probably explains why it was considered safer to forbid numbers starting with non significative `0` in JSON.

Comment: Great answer. worth mentioning that octal literals are also forbidden in JavaScript strict mode. You'll get the following error in JavaScript  `SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.`

Answer (score -3):

remove 0 in front of the number in the json

Comment: Please provide more details/code for how this answer solves the question.